# Juntar uma celulas de uma tabela html [fechado]

Tags: php, html, table

A minha tabela está assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas queria que aparecesse o valor total numa só celula não separasse em varios valores totais.Exp:

### Data|Nome|valor

### 2020-02-12|a|1.00€

### 2020-02-12|b|1.00€

### Valor Total|2.00€

Código:

```
<table style="width: 50%;" border='0' id="table" name="table">
<tr>
<th width="10%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Data</th>
<th width="25%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Nome do custo</th>
<th width="8%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Valor</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td align="left" bgcolor="white">'.$registo['data'].'</td>';
        echo'<td bgcolor="white">'.$registo['nome_custo'].'</td>';
    if($registo['valor']>=$registo['valor'].".00"){
        $valor=$registo['valor'].".00";
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$valor."€</td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor=$valor' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>");
    }
    else{
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$registo['valor']."€></td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor={$registo['valor']}' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>"); 

    }
    if($registo['valor']){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' colspan='2' bgcolor='#baba84'><b>Valor Total</b></td>
    <?php
        $valor_total=0; 
        $valor_total = $valor_total+$registo['valor'];

        if($valor_total>=$valor_total.".00"){
            $valor_t=$valor_total.".00";
    ?>
        <td align='left' bgcolor='white'><?php echo $valor_t."€"?></td>
    <?php
        }
        else{
    ?>
        <td align='left' bgcolor='white'><?php echo $valor_total."€"?></td> 
    <?php
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Podiam me ajudar a identificar o erro que estou a fazer para ficar assim a tabela.

Comment: Tente dissertar melhor sobre o que precisa, está muito confuso...

Comment: @JaksonFischer ja fiz um exemplo

Comment: Está um pouco confuso, poderia exemplificar melhor?

Comment: @MateusD. exemplificar como eu fiz um exemplo como quero a tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um count ou sizeof no seu array para saber quantos registros você tem, assim você só vai exibir o total quando o array for lido até o final... exemplo:

não sei se ta tudo certinho, mas a idéia é essa, veja se te ajuda.

```
   <table style="width: 50%;" border='0' id="table" name="table">
   <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Data</th>
        <th width="25%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Nome do custo</th>
        <th width="8%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$total_valor = 0;

while($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

    // nao vou mexer aqui mas da para melhorar.
    echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td align="left" bgcolor="white">'.$registo['data'].'</td>';
        echo'<td bgcolor="white">'.$registo['nome_custo'].'</td>';
    if($registo['valor']>=$registo['valor'].".00"){
        $valor=$registo['valor'].".00";
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$valor."€</td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor=$valor' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>");
    }
    else{
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$registo['valor']."€></td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor={$registo['valor']}' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>"); 

    }

    // soma todos os valores
    $total_valor += $registo['valor'];


}

?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' colspan='2' bgcolor='#baba84'><b>Valor Total</b></td>
        <td align='left' bgcolor='white'><?php echo number_format($total_valor, 2, ',', '.'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104995/discussion-on-answer-by-dih-centioli-juntar-uma-celulas-de-uma-tabela-html-fech)

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu caso sugiro usar array_sum().
Após a soma vc pode criar um tfooter e colocar os valores como última opção.
Segue link da documentação.
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php

Comment: Já consegui resolver, mas obrigado na mesma por ter respondido.